# Razor Pages/ ASP.NET CORE Routing Issue on Deployed Site (404 Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

When I deploy my site it changes the generated anchor link for certain items. On my local server the link turns out to be http://localhost:49377/Recipe/1 and it works when I click it. On my deployed server it shows thedeployedsserver.net/Home/Index/1?page=%2FRecipe .

It's this link in the Menu.cshtml that changes:

```
<h3><a asp-page="/Recipe" asp-route-id="@recipe.Id">@recipe.Name</a></h3>
```

I think it's maybe some routing issue but I don't know what it is. I'm still looking through the documentation but hopefully, someone can help me or point me in the right direction.

I have the following code in my Menu.cshtml

```
@page
@{
    var recipes = await RecipesService.GetAllAsync();
}
@section Title {
    <h2 class="title">My Favorite Recipes</h2>
}

<div class="row recipes">

    @foreach (var recipe in recipes)
    {
        <div class="recipe col-md-4 burgerBlackBoard">
            <img class="img burgerImage" src="@recipe.GetInlineImageSrc()" />
            <h3><a asp-page="/Recipe" asp-route-id="@recipe.Id">@recipe.Name</a></h3>
        </div>

    }
</div>
```

This is my Recipe.cshtml page:

```
@page "{id}"
@{
    var id = long.Parse((string)RouteData.Values["id"]);
    var recipe = await RecipesService.FindAsync(id);

    ViewData["Title"] = recipe.Name;
}

    <div class="row recipe burgerBlackBoard">
        <div class="col-6 ">
            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                <span class="description">
                    @recipe.Description
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2 text-center">
                <img class="img burgerImage" src="@recipe.GetInlineImageSrc()" />
            </div>
            <hr />
        </div>
        <div class="ingredients col-6">
            <h3 class="text-center">Ingredients</h3>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var ingredient in recipe.IngredientsList)
                {
                    <li>@ingredient</li>
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My startup.cs that holds my routing:

```
public class Startup
{
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie();
        services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Admin");
            options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account");
            options.Conventions.AllowAnonymousToPage("/Account/Login");
        }); //dependency injection
        services.AddTransient<IRecipesService, RecipesService>();


    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue. Seems I had a separate model named Recipe and a Page named Recipe and their names were conflicting. I just created another page named Burgers and it fixed the conflict with the routing issue.

Answer (score 0):

It thinks you are using the home controller and the index view.

instead of asp-page can you use asp-controller and asp-action.  If you share your route setup, I can provide a better answer.

Comment: I think you might be right but I'm perplexed on how to go about changing it. I updated the original post with the Starup.cs file that holds my routing information.

Comment: Is you controller RecipesService and in that class there is a recipe method? So it would be asp-controller= recipesservice asp-action= recipe

Comment: RecipeService is a model that inherits the IRecipesService interface. I changed the it to asp-controller and asp-action and it didn't work.

Comment: The other issue is why does it work on the local server but not on azure when deployed?

Answer (score 0):

In your link change /Recipe to ./Recipe

```
<h3><a asp-page="./Recipe" asp-route-id="@recipe.Id">@recipe.Name</a></h3>
```

Comment: I changed it to that before and it didn't do it. I tried it again but it's not working.